# How to sort items in Recyclerview while its Activity is in onStop() state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have list of items in RecyclerView. Items can change their positions on their data changes. Data of items can change when this activity is not visible(app is closed, or user has opened another activity over this one). For example when my activity is in onStop state, and I update my items in adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` items only sorted when I resume this activity(I can see how they change their places).

I want to resume my activity with already new state(items should already have to be in their new positions).

**Extra detail:** I also enabled default animation for RecyclerView
`adapter.setHasStableIds(true);`

Comment: Call recyclerview.requestLayout() and recyclerview.invalidate() after notifyDataSetChanged(), see if the view can be relayouted when not visible.

Comment: recyclerview.invalidate() in onStop is definitely an option

Comment: I tried adding `recyclerview.requestLayout()` and `recyclerview.invalidate()` when data changes (after `notifyDataSetChanged()`). Also tried doing it onStart. Still same: items change their position only when I resume activity.

Comment: After disabling animation `adapter.setHasStableIds(true);` groups got sorted in background

Comment: Thus I need to find way to disable animation when activity is in stopped state, and enable it when its resumed.

Comment: finally I got it work like I want. To enable RecyclerView animation if sorting happening while list is visible I use `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());` if Activity goes background, onPause I use `recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);` to disable animation. This way when I resume the Activity I got already sorted list.